# Avoid locks in Oracle UPDATE command

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, locking

If I am trying to acquire a lock in Oracle 10g (e.g. with `SELECT...FOR UPDATE`), there is a `NOWAIT` option to get an error when the row is locked, instead of the query just hanging. Is there a way to achive this for a simple `UPDATE` statement? There is a [DDL_LOCK_TIMEOUT](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/initparams068.htm) option in Oracle 11g, I would need something similar for DML operations (and in 10g).

(Background: I have some unit tests which query the database (which is unfortunately not an isolated test database, but a developement DB used for various things), and I want them to throw an error instantly instead of hanging when anything goes wrong.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle: no wait / no fail on update statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545782/oracle-no-wait-no-fail-on-update-statement)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  There is no way to have a simple UPDATE statement in Oracle time out if some other session has locked the row it is trying to update.  You could, of course, code your unit tests to do a `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE WAIT <<n>>` before doing the UPDATE.  That would ensure that by the time you got to the UPDATE, you would be guaranteed to already have the lock.

I'm also a bit confused by the idea that you'd be running unit tests against rows that other sessions are modifying at the same time you are.  That would seem to defeat the purpose of having unit tests since it would never be clear whether a test failed because the code did something wrong or because some other session modified the data in an unexpected way during the test.

Comment: As I said it is unfortunate, but I seem to be stuck with it for the moment. It still seems better to catch the ORA-00054 and mark that test as inconclusive than the whole testing process grinding to a halt because someone is doing something slow to a table.

Comment: +1 and +2 if I could. Unit testing should ideally be done on rows that are created in the first step of your unit test and removed at the end of the test or on data which you know cannot be modified.